# CGAL: Wrong vertex accessed using facet

Tags: c++, cgal

As far as I understand how a facet works in CGAL (using v5.1), it is composed of a cell handle and an index to the vertex opposing the facet in that cell handle. One can thus obtains all the vertex of the considered cell using (I am working using alpha-shapes in 3D):

```cpp
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel                     Kernel;
typedef Kernel::FT                                                              FT;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<std::size_t, Kernel>        Vb3;
typedef CGAL::Fixed_alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<Kernel, Vb3>                      asVb3;
typedef CGAL::Fixed_alpha_shape_cell_base_3<Kernel>                             asCb3;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<asVb3, asCb3>                      asTds3;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<Kernel, asTds3, CGAL::Fast_location>     asTriangulation_3;
typedef CGAL::Fixed_alpha_shape_3<asTriangulation_3>                            Alpha_shape_3;
typedef Kernel::Point_3                                                         Point_3;

...

Alpha_shape_3::Facet facet;

...

Alpha_shape_3::Vertex_handle facetV1 = facet.first->vertex((facet.second+1)%4);
Alpha_shape_3::Vertex_handle facetV2 = facet.first->vertex((facet.second+2)%4);
Alpha_shape_3::Vertex_handle facetV3 = facet.first->vertex((facet.second+3)%4);
Alpha_shape_3::Vertex_handle facetOppositeVertex = facet.first->vertex((facet.second)%4);
```

I assumed the opposite vertex is inside a cell, and the facet is also part of this cell. Using this, I can compute the exterior-pointing normals to the surface of my alpha-shape (if there is a way to do this automatically using CGAL, I would like to know it). To compute the normal of a point on the free surface, I do an average of the the different facet normals sharing that point, weighted by the angle of the facet at that point. To orient my normals exteriorly to the mesh, I simply check the dot product between the normal and a vector from one point of the facet to the opposite vertex.

The problem is that, sometimes the opposite vertex seems to be in a complete different cell, leading in my FEM computations to bad results. Here are some figures of what happen:

- initially
  [Normal to free surface (good)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO4Fn.png)
- when the mesh slightly deforms:
  [Normal to free surface (bad)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PGI0.png)

Actually what happens is that the opposite vertex of some facet does not lie in the only cell sharing that free surface facet, but inside another cell far away, such that the orientation of the facet normal is not correctly computed, and that some facet normals cancel each other, leading thus to bad normals.

Is there:

- a way to compute those normals automatically in cgal ?
- a problem in my understanding of how a facet works ?

NB: I already check when the opposite vertex is infinite and in that case I mirror the facet using the `mirror_facet` function

EDIT:

As mentionned in a comment, I tried to use different functions to access the vertex:

```cpp
std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
std::cout << facet.first->vertex(asTriangulation_3::vertex_triple_index(facet.second, 0))->info() << std::endl; //facetV1
std::cout << facet.first->vertex(asTriangulation_3::vertex_triple_index(facet.second, 1))->info() << std::endl; //facetV2
std::cout << facet.first->vertex(asTriangulation_3::vertex_triple_index(facet.second, 2))->info() << std::endl; //facetV3
std::cout << facet.first->vertex(asTriangulation_3::vertex_triple_index(facet.second, 3))->info() << std::endl; //opposite vertex
std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
```

But it sometimes gives me:

```
--------------------------------------------------
117
25
126
117
--------------------------------------------------
```

So an opposite vertex with the same index as one of the facet's vertex.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get a consistent orientation of vertices in a face is to use the function [vertex_triple_index()](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/TDS_3/structCGAL_1_1Triangulation__utils__3.html#a71288c8c2833f954a73090336ed60054) instead of (+1/2/3%4). So you have:

```
Alpha_shape_3::Vertex_handle facetV1 = facet.first->vertex(DT::vertex_triple_index(facet.second,0));
Alpha_shape_3::Vertex_handle facetV2 = facet.first->vertex(DT::vertex_triple_index(facet.second,1));
Alpha_shape_3::Vertex_handle facetV3 = facet.first->vertex(DT::vertex_triple_index(facet.second,2));
```

Comment: Okay, that's great. However, my problem is more on obtaining the right opposite vertex.

Comment: Do you mean it does not solve your problem? What do you mean by "right"?

Comment: As I said in the post, I assume the opposite vertex and the facet are in the same cell. But in practice, it is not the case at all (which leads to bad computed normals).

I also asked if there is a way to compute facet normals in cgal.

Comment: A facet is defined by a cell and the id of the vertex in that cell opposite to the considered facet. So the facet and the opposite vertex are in the same cell by definition. Then it might be that you are considering the wrong cell for what you are trying to do. Note that the code I gave is not an alternative way to access the vertices but the way to write it so that vertices are always picked in counterclockwise order.

Comment: "The facet and the opposite vertex are in the same cell by definition", indeed. But why then, when I get from the alpha shape the opposite vertex, is it sometimes not laying in the cell at all?

Can I access the opposite vertex using `facet.first->vertex(DT::vertex_triple_index(facet.second, 3));` ? 
Will it give me a different result than
`facet.first->vertex(facet.second%4);` ?

Comment: Yes it will not give you the same result, which is why I'm mentioning it. Depending on whether the opposite vertex is odd or even, +k%4 can be clockwise or counterclockwise and thus give the opposite normal that you'd expect.

Comment: Okay, I tried to use this `vertex_triple_index` in my code (see main pors edit). Unfortunately, it sometimes gives me an opposite vertex whose index is the same as one of the facet's vertex.

Comment: `std::cout << facet.first->vertex(asTriangulation_3::vertex_triple_index(facet.second, 3))->info() << std::endl; //opposite vertex` is not valid (underneath there is a static array IIRC). Use `std::cout <<  facet.first->vertex(facet.second)->info() << std::endl;` to get the opposite vertex.